# deleting related models django

Tags: django, django-models

i currently have this models how do i delete the logo without deleting the company model.Please sample codes if possible thanks.

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,blank = True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank = True, null = True)

class Company(GenericUser):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank = True,null = True)
    logo = models.ForeignKey(Picture,blank = True,null = True)
```

this is a model how will i then remove the foto from the land model the model looks like this.

```
class Land(Properies):
    photo = models.ManyToManyField(Picture,blank=True,related_name='Land_Pictures',null = True)
```

i tried this bit it dose not work

```
checked_list = []
start = 1            
land_photos = sorted(list(land.photo.select_related()),reverse =True)
while start < 8:
    photo = 'photo%s' % start
    checked = form.cleaned_data[photo]
    if checked != None:
        checked_list.append(land_photos[start - 1])
        start += 1            
for a_foto in checked_list:
land.photo.remove(a_foto)
try:
    a_foto.remove_all_file()
    a_foto.delete()
except OSError:
    pass
```

i keep getting an error like that id is set to none and if i hit refresh it works i think

```
Exception Type:     AssertionError
Exception Value:    
Picture object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Company model this way:

```
class Company(GenericUser):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank = True,null = True)
    logo = models.ForeignKey(Picture,blank = True,null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: Are you using Django>=1.4? on_delete option was presented in Django 1.4 and does not work in previous Django versions.

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear the references from any Company objects to the Picture object you want to delete.

```
logo = company.logo
company.logo = None
logo.delete()
```

However, if a Picture is referenced by multiple Companies, try this:

```
logo = Picture.object.get(...) # the Picture you want to delete
logo.company_set.update(logo=None)
logo.delete()
```

You should also consider changing the reference from Company to Image so related instances do not get deleted by default.

```
class Company(GenericUser):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank = True,null = True)
    logo = models.ForeignKey(Picture,blank = True,null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: thanks all i tried the 1st 2 approaches but they did not work the way i expected maybe its because its more complicated than the way i show in the version i displayed but @DanielHepper you approach worked like a charm thanks a million

Comment: how do i do this in a m2m situation

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason:

a) you are using `(GenericUser)`? This will undoubtedly cause you problems.

b) can't just delete the attribute (per below) and then migrate the data?

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,blank = True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank = True, null = True)

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    logo = models.ForeignKey(Picture, blank=True, null=True)
```

or are you trying to delete a related instance per here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove

In which case you'd use `remove()`.

Comment: GenericUser is another model the company inherits from when i delete the logo the company gets deleted too

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'